# Одинаковая высота flex элементов

Tags: flexbox

Как сохранить высоту flex элемента при переносе на следующую строку.
Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/durgtym6/6/

```css
.post-desc__other-offer-wrap {
    margin: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    color: #525252;
}
.post-desc__other-offer-item {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-desc__other-offer-wrap">
  <p class="post-desc__other-offer-item">Смартфон в режиме точки доступа
  </p>
  <p class="post-desc__other-offer-item">USB-модем
  </p>
  <p class="post-desc__other-offer-item">Мобильное устройство
  </p>
  <p class="post-desc__other-offer-item">Однооператорный роутер
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью flexbox сделать это [невозможно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004926/equal-height-rows-in-a-flex-container). Похожего эффекта можно добиться с помощью `display: grid`.